# Cannot write formula excel to cell with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

i am creating interactive excel, and i am using openpyxl library. For some reason excel cannot be loaded according to error with formula. There is how i put formula in cell:

```
ws = self.wb.create_sheet('help')
ws['C6'] = '=IFERROR(FILTER(other_sheet!B3:B12; other_sheet!D3:D12=main_sheet!C3; "No results"); "error")'
```

Formula work, when I directly pass them to excel, also the way i did is correct. Basic formulas instead of FILTER works (eg. sum). I assumed that this formula didnt work with openpyxl. And i should use built-in function in openpyxl but imo it won't work dynamically (eg. this statement: other_sheet!D3:D12=main_sheet!C3)

I saw that in manual is obligatory to use comas, so i applied it. But it still doesnt work

```
ws['C6'] = '=FILTER(other_sheet!B3:B12, other_sheet!D3:D12=main_sheet!C3, "No results")'
```

But it doesnt change anything, problem still appears. Any suggestions?
I also tried with ws['C6'].value

Comment: `I discovered that i should use coma instead of semicolon` Well the manual clearly states in orange, with a big warning sign `NB you must use the English name for a function and function arguments must be separated by commas and not other punctuation such as semi-colons`  so it's not much about discovering but rather reading the manual https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae

Comment: Yes, but i did in that way, and it doesnt work.

Comment: Any function you write to excel won't work "dynamically" in openpyxl as it doesn't evaluate formula - excel does the evaluation. You also do need to use `ws['C6'].value` as you suggested. Have you tried running this exact formula, copy and pasted, in Excel?

Comment: Yes i tried, and with semicolon it worked.